# Как поставить библиотеку SDL in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, sdl2

Привет я хочу изучить библиотеку SDL. Вот я его могу подключить в Visual Studio, а как его подключить в Visual Code. В интернете не нашел(может плохо искал)

Comment: а как компилируете-линукете в visual studio code?

Comment: отвяжитесь от IDE-зависимых штук - изучите cmake

Comment: опять комент не в тему, что бы только cmake попиарить.